# What is the point of istringstream with openmode ios_base::out

Tags: c++, stringstream

What it is the purpose of the [`istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) constructor argument `openmode`?

In particular is there any point to specifying `ios_base::out` since I think this object never supports the stream insertion `<<` operator?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but istringstream does inherit from istream which uses openmode for its operations

Comment: @brettmichaelgreen - yeah I saw that, but I wondered why that is exposed in the istringstream constructor: it could just choose to pass the correct value of openmode.

Comment: Possibly to allow the user to enable `binary` mode on the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Streams with `ios_base::in` access mode do not support any output operations. Methods altering the sequence will fail if `ios_base::out` isn't specified.

From [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/)

> Open mode: Access given by the internal stringbuf object to its internal sequence of characters.
>
> `ios_base::out` -  output  -  The sequence **supports output operations**.
>
> `ios_base::in` is always set for `istringstream` objects (even if explicitly not set in argument which).
>   Note that even though `istringstream` is an input stream, its internal stringbuf object may be set to also support output operations. This influences certain operations, such as [`putback`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback), that in `istringstream` may alter the contents of the sequence.

See `putback` [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da8856dbc54b6d36) :

```cpp
        std::istringstream s1("Hello, world", std::ios_base::out); //  stream supporting output operations
        s1.get();
        if (s1.putback('Y')) // modifies the buffer
            std::cout << s1.rdbuf() << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "putback failed\n";

        std::istringstream s2("Hello, world"); // input-only stream
        s2.get();
        if (s2.putback('Y')) // cannot modify input-only buffer
            std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "putback failed\n";

        s2.clear();
        if (s2.putback('H')) // non-modifying putback is OK
            std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "putback failed\n";
```